# Magento: Add captcha to custom contact form

Tags: magento, customization, captcha, contact-form

I created a new custom contact form in Magento website, I am trying to add captcha at the end of it.

I have added to app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml

```
                <customcontacts>
                    <label>Custom Contact Form</label>
                </customcontacts>
```

And I added to app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml

```
    <customcontacts>
    <reference name="customcontacts">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>customcontacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customcontacts>
```

And I added to my form this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('form-validate-captcha').captcha.refresh($('catpcha-reload'));
//]]>
```

And I added this code to show the Captcha:

```
<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha'); ?></div>
```

Then I enabled Captcha in Configuration > Customer Configuration > CAPTCHA and I choose "Custom Contact Form" then "Displaying Mode" to "Always".

But I still didn't get the Captcha at my custom form yet.

I hope I was clear

Thanks

Comment: Khali,check now my answer

Comment: I am working on it, I hope it works for custom contact form this is it: www.cabas-durables.fr/custom-contact/

Comment: My custom contact ID is `<?php echo Mage::helper('customcontacts')->__('Demande de devis personnalisé') ?>`, does that help?

Answer (score 3):

if ,you want to add  magento `own captcha to contact us form` ,then follow below step.....

Donot write code in code file `create an extension`

Step1: Create module control file

path `app/etc/modules/Amit_Captchaown.xml` add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
<Amit_Captchaown>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
<depends>
<Mage_Captcha/>
</depends>
</Amit_Captchaown>
</modules>
</config>
```

Step2:

Create module config.xml file in `app/code/local/Amit/Captchaown/etc/config.xml`.Rewrite model of `zend and captcha controllers` and here code

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Amit_Captchaown>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</Amit_Captchaown>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
    <captcha>
        <rewrite>
        <zend>Amit_Captchaown_Model_Zend</zend>
        </rewrite>
        </captcha>
    </models>
</global>
<default>
    <captcha  translate="label">
    <frontend>
    <areas>
    <contact_us>
    <label>Contact us Form</label>
    </contact_us>
    </areas>
    </frontend>
    </captcha>

    <customer>
    <captcha>
    <always_for>
    <contact_us>1</contact_us>
    </always_for>
    </captcha>
    </customer>
</default>
<frontend>
<routers>
<contacts>
<args>
<modules>
<amit_captchaown before="Mage_Contacts">Amit_Captchaown</amit_captchaown>
</modules>
</args>
</contacts>
</routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Step3:

Override `Mage_Captcha_Model_Zend file _isUserAuth()` function
create Zend.php file in `app/code/local/Amit/Captchaown/Model/Zend.php`.In this function you need to only comment function code.

```
<?php
class Amit_Captchaown_Model_Zend extends Mage_Captcha_Model_Zend
{

protected function _isUserAuth()
{
/* return Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()
? Mage::getSingleton(‘admin/session’)->isLoggedIn()
: Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->isLoggedIn();*
*/
}

}
```

Step4:
Then add some code in contacts.xml path app/design/frontend/our package/your template/layout

add  and modify code is

```
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml">

            <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
            <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
            </reference>
            <action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_us</formId></action>
            <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
            <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
            </block>

</block>
</reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
```

Step5:

Then add code`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` to `form.phtml` path `app/design/frontend/our package/your template/tempate/contacts`.

Step6:

Now you need to override contact us controller create file in  app/code/local/Amit/Captchaown/controllers/IndexController.php....

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php');
class Amit_Captchaown_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{

public function postAction()
{
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if ( $post ) {
$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
/* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
$translate->setTranslateInline(false);
try {
$postObject = new Varien_Object();
$postObject->setData($post);

$error = false;

if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
$error = true;
}

if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
$error = true;
}

if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
$error = true;
}

if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
$error = true;
}

$formId ='contact_us';
$captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($this->getRequest(), $formId))) {
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
$this->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/'));
return;
}
}

if ($error) {
throw new Exception();
}
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
/* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
->setReplyTo($post['email'])
->sendTransactional(
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
null,
array('data' => $postObject)
);

if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
throw new Exception();
}

$translate->setTranslateInline(true);

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');

return;
} catch (Exception $e) {
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
return;
}

} else {
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
}

protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
{
$captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
return $captchaParams[$formId];
}

}
```

Now just enable `captcha` in `contact us form` go to your admin panel setting `sytem->configuration->customer configuration->Captcha`

Comment: It works on admin now, I can see "Custom Contact Form" been added to the captcha list as I named it, but after saving the configuration nothing appears in the page, I added the line in my form.phtml file like that: `<tr><td><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?></td></tr>
`, is there is anything need to be added more, Thank you

Comment: please try with fresh

Comment: I got error at http://www.cabas-durables.fr/custom-contact/ at the end of the page says:  Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in /home/cabasdfr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43

Comment: This is line 24 in IndexController.php `->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/send') );`

Comment: There was the issue for class name Amit_Captchaown_Model_Zend  ,i have modify it for Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in

Comment: Sorry Amit, After you fix your codes now I can't see "Contact Form" in sytem->configuration->customer configuration->Captcha list

Comment: How to show captcha in custom form, I am showing contact form in footer, I need to show captcha there..

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a variation of Amit Bera's answer that's simple to implement: the *"are you people" written question and answer*.

In `Admin -> System -> Custom Variables` create two variables:

[image]

Edit your template file for the contact form *(might be somewhere else if you purchased a template)* `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml`

Near the top, just under the header, I added these lines to retrieve the custom variables information and then in the script tags, added the custom validation function to the Validation class declared in prototype JS. By having the javascript in the template file, you are able to dynamically set the question's answer variable via php.

```
<?php 
$confirm_people_question = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->loadByCode('contact_people_question')
    ->getValue('text');
$confirm_people_answer = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->loadByCode('contact_people_answer')
    ->getValue('text');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
Validation.add(
    'validate-people','Incorrect answers prevent automated emails'
    ,function(v){
    var m="<?php echo $confirm_people_answer ?>";
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || (v==m);
});
</script>
```

Further down in the same `template/contacts/form.phtml` file, add in the new field to the form itself:

```
<li>
    <label for="people" class="required"><em>*</em>
    <?php echo $confirm_people_question ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input  name="people" id="people" 
                title="Please confirm you are people" value="" 
                class="required-entry input-text validate-people" type="text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

Note the `validate-people` text is the same in `<input class=""` attribute as well as in the javascript function we added above.

**End result:**
[image]